# MAX77651 Can't read register with i2c

Tags: c, microcontroller, i2c

I am trying to test the i2c communication of the MAX77651 chip before programming it.

So here is my setup to do so:

I have an UMFT4222ev connected to my Linux laptop by USB. This chip has his SCL and SDA linked to the SDA and SCL of my MAX77651 thanks to the Evaluation Kit for the MAX77651. My MAX77651evkit is powered with 3,7V on the Vbatt pin.

I also installed the mraa librarie from git hub and the libft4222. I know mraa is well installed because i tried it with and example.

I was told that the mraa library takes in charge the setup of the FT4222 so i only used mraa functions to make my program.

I searched on the website of Maxim integrated the i2c slave address and one register where i could read data and check if everyting is working. I then read the i2c protocol of communication to read a single register which is available here : https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX77650-MAX77651.pdf at the page 78.

With all those informations I tried to make my "test program". I solved the compiling errors but when I execute the program I can't get what is in the register which should be 0xFF.

Here is my program:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "syslog.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "mraa/i2c.h"
#include "mraa.h"

#define I2C_ADDR 0x48

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
uint8_t *message;
*message=0XAC;
int i,j,k;
char reg_a_lire = 0x06; 

mraa_init();    
mraa_i2c_context i2c;


i2c = mraa_i2c_init(0);
mraa_i2c_frequency(i2c,MRAA_I2C_FAST);


mraa_i2c_address(i2c, I2C_ADDR);

mraa_i2c_write_byte(i2c,0x90);


mraa_i2c_read(i2c, message,1);


mraa_i2c_write_byte(i2c,reg_a_lire);


mraa_init();


mraa_i2c_write_byte(i2c,0x91);

mraa_i2c_read(i2c, message,1);

mraa_i2c_read(i2c, message,1);

printf("%02X \n", *message);
mraa_i2c_stop(i2c);

return 0;
}
```

Here is the actual output :

```
alex@cyclonit-laptop ~/Test_alex/tests $ ./a.out
AC
```

And i would like to get FF instead of AC.

I think my error could come from something i missed to initialize the FT4222 or from the MAX77651 which I maybe did nt power up correctly and its not sufficient to put 3,7V on Vbatt. But maybe this is a problem with my program because i don't know much about uint8_t and I made something wrong.

I am hoping someone has experience with FT4222 and/or MAX77651 and can help me.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Please post your code (not an image), and highlight the problem (which is somewhat difficult to find in your long post at the moment): the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: Thank you i will try to highlight the problem better,  but I don't know yet how to post the code properly the only solution I found as putting an image.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I tried to edit my post to make it better tell me if i can still make more changes i am new here.

Comment: This question is more suitable for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/, especially if you suspect that it could also be a hardware issue. If you ask there however, make sure to include some manner of schematic (the site has a simple schematic tool built-in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to read I2C registers of MAX77651.

First looking at the hardware part I had to make sure that VIO had the right voltage like @FRob said in hid comment.

Then for the software, I stopped using the mraa library because i could'nt control everything. I used the FT4222 library which allowed me to open and initiate the FT4222 device. I took some part of the I2C example in this library for the initialization of the device. Then I noticed that I had to first use the FT4222's write function to send the register i wanted to read , then simply use the read function to get my result. Those are the two steps required.

I won't post the whole program i made as it is mainly taken from the I2C example for initialization but here is the part I added to read my register 0X06 which is supposed to contain 0xFF:

```
uint8 resultat=0x11;
uint8 *p_resultat=&resultat;
int chiffre;
slaveAddr
uint16 bytesToWrite2 = 1;
uint16 bytesWritten2=1;
uint8 valeur= 0x06;                              // REGISTER TO READ
uint8 *p_valeur=&valeur;    


FT4222_I2CMaster_Write(ftHandle,slaveAddr,
p_valeur,bytesToWrite2,&bytesWritten);  //INDICATES WHICH REGISTER TO 
                                        //                       READ

chiffre = FT4222_I2CMaster_Read(ftHandle, 
slaveAddr,p_resultat,1, &bytesRead);     // READ REGISTER

printf("The content of the register %02X is : %02X \n " , 
valeur,resultat);    // DISPLAY RESULT

printf("reading success if : %d = 0 \n " , chiffre);                 
// READING SUCCESS ?
```

With this code and the initialization i get the following result :

```
alex@cyclonit-laptop ~/Downloads/libft4222-1.2.1.4/examples $ ./a.out

Device 0 is interface A of mode-0 FT4222H:
0x0403601c    FT4222 A
Chip version: 42220200, LibFT4222 version: 01020104
The content of the register 06 is : FF 
reading success if : 0 = 0 
Skipping interface B of mode-0 FT4222H.
```

If someone has the same problem you are free to ask me your question by answering this post.I am very thankful to the people here who helped me!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused by pg. 75 [of the MAX77651 datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX77650-MAX77651.pdf).

```
ADDRESS      | 7-BIT SLAVE ADDRESS | 8-BIT WRITE ADDRESS | 8-BIT READ ADDRESS
Main Address | 0x48, 0b 100 1000   | 0x90, 0b 1001 0000  | 0x91, 0b 1001 0001
(ADDR = 1)*  |                     |                     |                   
-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------
Main Address | 0x40, 0b 100 0000   | 0x80, 0b 1000 0000  | 0x81, 0b 1000 0001
(ADDR = 0)*  |                     |                     |
```

Depending on your view of the I²C specification, you either use the 7-bit address or use both 8-bit addresses. The reason is that the first I²C transaction sends the following 8 bit:

```
76543210
\_____/\-- R/#W
   \------ 7-bit Slave Address
```

In your case that's `0x48` shifted one bit to the left followed by either a `1` for read mode or a `0` for write mode. Notice that

```
(0x40 << 1) | 0x00 == 0x80 == 8-bit Write Address (ADDR = 0)
(0x40 << 1) | 0x01 == 0x81 == 8-bit Read Address  (ADDR = 0)
(0x48 << 1) | 0x00 == 0x90 == 8-bit Write Address (ADDR = 1)
(0x48 << 1) | 0x01 == 0x91 == 8-bit Read Address  (ADDR = 1)
```

Some people like to use the slave address while other people prefer to give separate addresses so it's clear what the first byte of communication will look like.

So you should remove the extraneous `mraa_i2c_write_byte(i2c, ...);` lines from your code, as their intention seems to be to send the read or write address to the slave.

Check out the [MRAA library API reference](http://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/mraa/i2c_8h.html). There are functions that abstract reading and writing registers, either byte-wide [8-bit] registers or word-wide [16-bit] registers:

```
mraa_i2c_read_byte_data
mraa_i2c_read_bytes_data
mraa_i2c_write_byte_data
```

In both cases you should check the return codes to know if the action succeeded. In your case, your `message` is likely not altered, because there was a stop/error condition beforehand, because the slave did either not ACK its slave address or it did not ACK the 0x90/0x91 data bytes you mistakenly sent, as they don't show up in the [Programmer's Guide](http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN6428.pdf) as valid addresses.

Another issue is that you try to read register INTM_GLBL (0x06; Global Interrupt Mask Register) using two consecutive read operations. I'm not sure if your intention is to read register 0x06 twice or if you intended to read INT_M_CHG (0x07; Global Interrupt Mask for Charger), because that's not what it will do. Notice the description on pg. 78 of the [datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX77650-MAX77651.pdf):

```
Note that when the MAX77650/MAX77651 receive a stop 
they do not modify their register pointer.
```

This is typical behavior for I²C slaves that support multi-byte/sequential reads. You will have to issue a sequential read operation for multiple bytes of data if you want to read multiple registers, e.g. using `mraa_i2c_read_bytes_data`.

Something like the following might get you on the right track. It is supposed to read the CID and CLKS settings and wait forever if a read error occurred. If successful, it will disable charging, all outputs, setup the red LED to blink once every other second and -- as soon as you uncomment it -- transition the On/Off Controller into On Via Software state to enable bias and the LED.

```
#define MAX77651_SLA     0x48u
#define CNFG_GLBL_REG    0x10u
#define CID_REG          0x11u
#define CNFG_CHG_B_REG   0x19u
#define CNFG_SBB0_B_REG  0x2Au
#define CNFG_SBB1_B_REG  0x2Cu
#define CNFG_SBB2_B_REG  0x2Eu
#define CNFG_LDO_B_REG   0x39u
#define CNFG_LED1_A_REG  0x41u
#define CNFG_LED1_B_REG  0x44u
#define CNFG_LED_TOP_REG 0x46u

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    uint8_t data;
    int res;

    mraa_init(); 
    mraa_i2c_context i2c0;

    i2c0 = mraa_i2c_init(0);
    mraa_i2c_frequency(i2c0, MRAA_I2C_STD);
    mraa_i2c_address(i2c0, MAX77651_SLA);

    res = mraa_i2c_read_byte_data(i2c0, CID_REG);
    if (res < 0) {
        printf("Reading CID_REG failed.\n");
        mraa_i2c_stop(i2c0);
        while(1);
    }
    data = res;
    printf("CID_REG: CLKS = %02X CID = %02X\n", ((data & 0x70u) >> 4), (data & 0x0Fu));

    /* you should check return values here */
    mraa_i2c_write_byte_data(i2c0, 0x00u /* CHG_EN = off */,  CNFG_CHG_B_REG);
    mraa_i2c_write_byte_data(i2c0, 0x04u /* EN_LDO = off */,  CNFG_LDO_B_REG);
    mraa_i2c_write_byte_data(i2c0, 0x04u /* EN_SBB0 = off */, CNFG_SBB0_B_REG);
    mraa_i2c_write_byte_data(i2c0, 0x04u /* EN_SBB1 = off */, CNFG_SBB1_B_REG);
    mraa_i2c_write_byte_data(i2c0, 0x04u /* EN_SBB2 = off */, CNFG_SBB2_B_REG);

    /* set up red led to toggle every second */
    mraa_i2c_write_byte_data(i2c0, 0x17u /* P = 1s, D = 50% */,         CNFG_LED1_B_REG);
    mraa_i2c_write_byte_data(i2c0, 0x98u /* FS = 6.4mA, BRT = 5.0mA */, CNFG_LED1_A_REG);
    mraa_i2c_write_byte_data(i2c0, 0x01u /* EN_LED_MSTR = on */,        CNFG_LED_TOP_REG);

    // DANGER ZONE: enable only when you know what this is supposed to do
    //mraa_i2c_write_byte_data(i2c0, 0x10u /* SBIA_EN = on, SBIA_LPM = normal */, CNFG_GLBL_REG);

    mraa_i2c_stop(i2c0);
    while(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer, I will try to modify my code thanks to your comment and post my feedback.

Comment: I tried to correct my errors.
First, you were write about slave adress, 0x48 was the good adress to put i was just mistaking about the ADDR bit.
Then i tried your program, exactly the same code but did'nt work i got Reading CID_RED failed.
I think the errors comes from the fact that to read/write with i2c on MAX77651 i have to follow a protocol of instructions before being able to write or read a single register. 
At least this is what i understand from page 78 of MAX77651's datasheet. 
So i will try to implement like this and give you feedback later.

Comment: @lsymap_prog This protocol is what I²C does and what the calls are supposed to do. Make sure that you actually connected VIO using J101 of the evkit as this supplies the I²C and GPIO cores. Make sure you measure both voltages and connect the right one for your I²C master.

Comment: Yes VIO is connected to 3,3v the led D102 is ON and red ( I measured the voltage with a multimeter) . I took a picture of my setup, but i am not sure if i am allowed to edit my question to post the picture. I tried again your code with and without 3,7v on Vbatt both failed. I also tried a sequential approach with start sequencing it did'nt work neither. 
If you have another idea and need more details tell me, but i am very thankful for all the time you spent for me already.

Comment: Well, according to my understanding of the datasheet, that should work. Did you check physical wiring, pull-up resistors? If all else fails, you will need an oscilloscope to look at the signals and see if the slave ACKs on SLA or if that already doesn't work. Not much that can be done remotely, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I checked it yes, i am pretty sure that everything is correct about hardware now.
The problem comes from the program with mraa and the FT4222, i think mraa does'nt initialize well FT4222 or makes something that does'nt match with my program. 
I will now try to do my program only using the FT4222 lib i installed on my computer because i can control everything with this library. Then i will give feedback there in case other people would have trouble programming MAX77651 using FT4222 like me.